# Unity Crash before start SplashScreen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I lost my day trying to find a solution for this issue, but I didn't have success. :(

The crash only appear in some devices and others work well, example, Nexus 5 works well, but in LG G5 or Samsung 7pol tablet crash before enter in unity SplashScreen.

The problem is I didn't understand what happen, why some devices work well and other not.

Thanks advance

I am using Unity 4.7 and the stacktrace is

```
07-19 19:10:58.764 29861-29861/com.game.custom D/HyLog: I : /data/font/config/sfconfig.dat, No such file or directory (2)
07-19 19:10:58.764 29861-29861/com.game.custom D/HyLog: I : /data/font/config/dfactpre.dat, No such file or directory (2)
07-19 19:10:58.764 29861-29861/com.game.custom D/HyLog: I : /data/font/config/sfconfig.dat, No such file or directory (2)
07-19 19:10:58.794 29861-29861/com.game.custom W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/external_SD/Android/obb/com.game.custom
07-19 19:10:58.804 29861-29861/com.game.custom W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/external_SD/Android/data/com.game.custom/files
07-19 19:10:58.824 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm: Could not find method org.fmod.FMODAudioDevice.close, referenced from method com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.f
07-19 19:10:58.824 29861-29861/com.game.custom W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 65081: Lorg/fmod/FMODAudioDevice;.close ()V
07-19 19:10:58.824 29861-29861/com.game.custom D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
07-19 19:10:58.824 29861-29861/com.game.custom E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.fmod.FMODAudioDevice', referenced from method com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.g
07-19 19:10:58.824 29861-29861/com.game.custom W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9675 (Lorg/fmod/FMODAudioDevice;) in Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;
07-19 19:10:58.824 29861-29861/com.game.custom D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0047
07-19 19:10:58.824 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm: Could not find method org.fmod.FMODAudioDevice.isRunning, referenced from method com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.g
07-19 19:10:58.824 29861-29861/com.game.custom W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 65082: Lorg/fmod/FMODAudioDevice;.isRunning ()Z
07-19 19:10:58.824 29861-29861/com.game.custom D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0054
07-19 19:10:58.824 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm: Could not find method org.fmod.FMODAudioDevice.stop, referenced from method com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.pause
07-19 19:10:58.824 29861-29861/com.game.custom W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 65084: Lorg/fmod/FMODAudioDevice;.stop ()V
07-19 19:10:58.824 29861-29861/com.game.custom D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0061
07-19 19:10:58.834 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm: Could not find method org.fmod.FMODAudioDevice.stop, referenced from method com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.restartFMODAudioDevice
07-19 19:10:58.834 29861-29861/com.game.custom W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 65084: Lorg/fmod/FMODAudioDevice;.stop ()V
07-19 19:10:58.834 29861-29861/com.game.custom D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-19 19:10:58.834 29861-29861/com.game.custom D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xfe38 at 0x49 in Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.g
07-19 19:10:58.834 29861-29861/com.game.custom D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.game.custom-1/libmain.so 0x4327e780
07-19 19:10:58.834 29861-29861/com.game.custom D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.game.custom-1/libmain.so 0x4327e780
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom W/dalvikvm: JNI WARNING: JNI function FatalError called with exception pending
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom W/dalvikvm:              in Lcom/unity3d/player/NativeLoader;.load:(Ljava/lang/String;)Z (FatalError)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom W/dalvikvm: Pending exception is:
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fmod/FMODAudioDevice
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.unity3d.player.NativeLoader.load(Native Method)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a((null):-1)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.<init>((null):-1)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.game.custom.UnityPlayerNativeActivity.onCreate(UnityPlayerNativeActivity.java:28)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.game.custom.MyCustomActivity.onCreate(MyCustomActivity.java:35)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm: Caused by:
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.fmod.FMODAudioDevice" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.game.custom-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.game.custom-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.unity3d.player.NativeLoader.load(Native Method)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a((null):-1)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.<init>((null):-1)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.game.custom.UnityPlayerNativeActivity.onCreate(UnityPlayerNativeActivity.java:28)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.game.custom.MyCustomActivity.onCreate(MyCustomActivity.java:35)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm: "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x417a3f48 self=0x416a7a98
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=29861 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074348372
07-19 19:10:58.844 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=4 core=0
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #00  pc 0000132e  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+29)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #01  pc 000638e6  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+33)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #02  pc 000578c4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+395)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #03  pc 00057932  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #04  pc 0003b94c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #05  pc 00044442  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #06  pc 003e1470  /data/app-lib/com.game.custom-1/libunity.so (JNI_OnLoad+332)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #07  pc 00003680  /data/app-lib/com.game.custom-1/libmain.so
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #08  pc 00003400  /data/app-lib/com.game.custom-1/libmain.so
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #09  pc 0002054c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #10  pc 0005132e  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+397)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #11  pc 000299e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #12  pc 00030f48  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #13  pc 0002e5e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #14  pc 00063af8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+391)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #15  pc 0006ba1e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #16  pc 000299e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #17  pc 00030f48  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #18  pc 0002e5e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #19  pc 00063814  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+335)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #20  pc 0004cf16  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #21  pc 0004e73c  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #22  pc 0004f496  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+353)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #23  pc 0000109a  /system/bin/app_process
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:   #24  pc 0000e5c8  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+47)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.unity3d.player.NativeLoader.load(Native Method)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a((null):-1)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.<init>((null):-1)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.game.custom.UnityPlayerNativeActivity.onCreate(UnityPlayerNativeActivity.java:28)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.game.custom.MyCustomActivity.onCreate(MyCustomActivity.java:35)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
07-19 19:10:58.854 29861-29861/com.game.custom A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000074a5 (code=-6), thread 29861 (m.game.custom)
```

Comment: Have you tried building using Unity 5.4 beta. They have issued many bug fixes for compiling to certain Android Devices.

Comment: @MyIsaak, I can't build with Unity 5.4 because my project is old. For it I need much time. I will check if I can build a blank project.